# Unable to determine query logic

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm learning SQL and am confused by the logic I've landed on.

My key questions are:

1. How does `d.name` get resolved? How does SQL know that I need to replace the `e.DepartmentID` with the name  `d.name` for a match on the `group by`
2. `d.name` has not been specified in `group by` and my understanding is that `group by` statement must have `d.name` in the select part of the query included but my query I built does not have that `d.name` in the `group by` statement. How is this working?

DB setup

```
Create table Departments (DepartmentID int primary key, Name text);

insert into Departments values
(1001,'SRO'),
(2001,'Drs'),
(3001,'Accounting');

Create table Employees 
(
  EmployeeID int not null, 
  DepartmentID int not null,
  ManagerID int,
  Name varchar(50) not null,
  Salary int not null,
  primary key(EmployeeID),
  foreign key (DepartmentID)
    references Departments(DepartmentID)
 );

insert into Employees values
(68319,1001,NULL,'Kayling','6000.00'),
(66928,3001,68319,'Blaze','2750.00'),
(67832,1001,68319,'Clare','2550.00'),
(65646,2001,68319,'Jonas','2957.00'),
(67858,2001,65646,'Scarlet','3100.00'),
(69062,2001,65646,'Frank','3100.00'),
(63679,2001,69062,'Sandrine','900.00'),
(64989,3001,66928,'Adelyn','1700.00'),
(65271,3001,66928,'Wade','1350.00');
```

My query

```
select d.name,
max(Salary)
from Employees e
  join Departments d on e.departmentID = d.departmentID
group by e.DepartmentID
```

The result from the query

```
name        max(Salary)
Drs         3100
Accounting  2750
SRO         6000
```

Comment: What do you mean by "resolve"? Why should that query return `e.DepartmentID` which you haven't specified in the `SELECT` clause?

Comment: @nbk no it will not throw an error in MySQL, because `e.DepartmentID` is a foreign key in `Employees` table and a primary key on `Departments` table, so all columns of the  `Departments` table are fully dependent on the `DepartmentID` . See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/6cI57tSL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called **functional dependency**. You group by department ID and thus get one row per department. There is only one row per department in the department table, so you can access all values of the departent row. This is how it is defined in the SQL standard.

Some DBMS are not capable of detecting functional dependency and require you to put all columns that you select in the `GROUP BY` clause. MySQL is not among them. It supports functional dependency, so this query is valid in MySQL.

Comment: Worth including [Detection of Functional Dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) in the answer